# AngularJS, $digest error trying to redirect application on pages requiring login

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to redirect an AngularJS app in the case that the requested state requires login.  This is the method I've placed within the 'run' method on my angular app:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

  if(toState.data.requiresLogin && !User.isLoggedIn)
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login');
  }
});
```

Seems straightforward, but I'm getting this digest error. It appears to be triggered by the event.preventDefault() statement.  I can't remove that of course...

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 7; oldVal: 6"],["fn:     $locationWatch; newVal: 8; oldVal: 7"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 9; oldVal: 8"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 10; oldVal: 9"],["fn: $locationWatch; newVal: 11; oldVal: 10"]]
...
```

Any advice on how to refactor this to clear this error, or what the error even means?

Comment: Have a look at this blog post it does exactly what you need http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLABnz?p=preview), how to redirect to login. Firstly there are 4 states defined - 2 of them **require** *authentication*, third is *public* *(for anybody)* and there is also *login* state:

```
$stateProvider
    // available for anybody
    .state('public',{
        url : '/public',
        template : '<div>public</div>',
    })
    // just for authenticated
    .state('some',{
        url : '/some',
        template : '<div>some</div>',
        data : {requiresLogin : true },
    })
    // just for authenticated
    .state('other',{
        url : '/other',
        template : '<div>other</div>',
        data : {requiresLogin : true },
    })
    // the log-on screen
    .state('login',{
        url : '/login',
        templateUrl : 'tpl.login.html',
        controller : 'UserCtrl',
    })
```

and that would be the `$stateChangeStart` def, which *always* redirects to `login` - if required ... only `login` itslef and `public` are available always/to anybody

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'User', function($rootScope, $state, User)
{

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'
    , function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    var isAuthenticationRequired =  toState.data 
          && toState.data.requiresLogin 
          && !User.isLoggedIn
      ;

    if(isAuthenticationRequired)
    {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('login');
    }
  });
}])
```

Check that all in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JLABnz?p=preview)