# Angularjs ui-router. How to redirect to login page

Tags: angularjs, config, state, angular-ui-router, resolve

I have 4 states: **dashboard**, **dahboard.main**, **dashboard.minor**, **login**.
dashboard is abstract and it is a parent state for .minor and .main states.
Below is my code:

```
.state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "views/dashboard.html",
        resolve: {
            auth: function ($q, authenticationSvc) {
                var userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();
                if (userInfo) {
                    return $q.when(userInfo);
                } else {
                    return $q.reject({ authenticated: false });
                }
            }
        },
        controller: "DashboardCtrl",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Example view' }
    })
    .state('dashboard.main', {
        url: "",
        templateUrl: "views/main.html",
        controller: "DashboardCtrl",
        data: { pageTitle: 'Main view' }
    })
```

As you see in dashboard state I have resolve option. By this I would like to redirect user to login page if he is not authorized. For this reason I use special **authenticationSvc** service:

```
.factory("authenticationSvc", ["$http", "$q", "$window", function ($http, $q, $window) {
    var userInfo;

    function login(email, password) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post("/api/login", { email: email, password: password })
            .then(function (result) {
                if(result.data.error == 0) {
                    userInfo = {
                        accessToken: result.data.accessToken
                    };
                    $window.sessionStorage["userInfo"] = JSON.stringify(userInfo);
                    deferred.resolve(userInfo);
                }
                else {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                }
            }, function (error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
    function getUserInfo() {
        return userInfo;
    }
    return {
        login: login,
        logout: logout,
        getUserInfo: getUserInfo
    };
}]);
```

I check auth value in **config** :

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$on("routeChangeSuccess", function(userInfo) {
        consol.log(userInfo);
    });
    $rootScope.$on("routeChangeError", function(event, current, previous, eventObj) {
        if(eventObj.authenticated === false) {
            $state.go('login');
        }
    });
});
```

But unfortunately when I go to my website root or dashboard state I get an empty page. What is wrong with this code? Thanks!

Comment: The event names are actually `$routeChangeSuccess` and `$routeChangeError` (note the leading `$`)...couldn't be as simple as that?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

The point is, do not redirect if not needed === if already redirected to intended state. There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3kImqU?p=preview) with similar solution

```
.run(function($rootScope, $location, $state, authenticationSvc) {


    $rootScope.$on( '$stateChangeStart', function(e, toState  , toParams
                                                   , fromState, fromParams) {

        var isLogin = toState.name === "login";
        if(isLogin){
           return; // no need to redirect 
        }

        // now, redirect only not authenticated

        var userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();

        if(userInfo.authenticated === false) {
            e.preventDefault(); // stop current execution
            $state.go('login'); // go to login
        }
    });
});
```

Check these for similar explanation:

- [Angular ui router - Redirection doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26135382/1679310)
- [How can I fix 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25028597/1679310)

Comment: Note to others: The code in this great answer is what you need.  The referenced Plunkr is nice, but is too verbose.

Comment: This example only works in legacy version (0.2). For newer versions (1.x), please read this migration guide: https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events

Answer (score 4):

Since you are using UI-Router module, you should be using `$stateChangeStart`, `$stateChangeSuccess` events.

Check this link for more: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/17

Also there is a typo in `consol.log(userInfo)` in **console**.

Check the console in your chrome-dev-tools. It will give idea if something else is missing.

Comment: Thanks! Now when I go to root of my website without authorization I am being redirected to login page, however when I go to dashboard state I have an empty page.

Comment: Have you checked what the console of the browser says..?

Comment: I have the same scenario today, where my dashboard state has a `resolve:`; however, inside my app.js watcher (`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart'`), it hangs on `event.preventDefault();` . I get the Angular Infinite Loop error. Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Beware that actually `$stateChangeSuccess` event is *deprecated* and no longer available in `angular-ui-route` package. Now, this behavior is handled by [`transition hooks`](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks). You could achieve your purpose using [`$transitions.onStart`](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/classes/transition.transition-1.html#onstart) as follows:

```
run.$inject = ['$transitions', 'authenticationSvc'];
function run($transitions, authenticationSvc) {

  $transitions.onStart({}, function (trans) {
    var userInfo = authenticationSvc.getUserInfo();

    var $state = trans.router.stateService;

    if(userInfo.authenticated === false) {
        $state.go('login'); // go to login
    }
  });
}
```