# Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded on Angular Ui Router State Change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Basically what I'm trying to do is change the state depending on user authentication status.

When I do `$state.go();` without $rootScope, I can redirect to the page without the error but when I do with

`$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event) {
     $state.go();
     event.preventDefault()
})`

Below Is the Controller Code:

```
DiaryDashboard.controller('AppController', 
  ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$localStorage', '$http', '$state'
  , function ($scope, $rootScope, $localStorage, $http, $state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

    if ($localStorage.userdetails &&
        $localStorage.userdetails.isAuthenticated == true) {

        //Check for Authentication state
        //If not redirect to the state in the else clause
        //Populate the $rootScope with user details
        $rootScope.userdetails = $localStorage.userdetails;

        //Switch to the parent state
        $state.go();
        event.preventDefault();

    } else {

        //If User not authenticated
        //GO to the Authentication State
        $state.go('auth');
        event.preventDefault();

    }
  })

}]);
```

Comment: the error is because of your code is causing infinite loop, when you call `$state.go()` it calls `$stateChangeStart` & this cycle going on

Comment: Can you plz help me on how to solve the problem?

Comment: could you tell me why `$state.go();` is required when user is authenticated..why you want to get back to parent state event if he is authenticated

Comment: I remove that but again the $state.go('auth') in the else block is giving the error

Comment: take a look at mine answer

Answer (score 4):

The most important thing here is to understand this:

> Do **not** redirect if not needed. Other words, if user is already redirected to intended state - we should leave... There is [a working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3kImqU?p=preview) with similar solution.

Check this Q & A:

#### [Angularjs ui-router. How to redirect to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27212182/1679310)

the adjusted code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

    var isNavigatingToAuth = toState.name === "Auth";

    if(isNavigatingToAuth){

       return; // no need to redirect 
    }

    if ($localStorage.userdetails &&
        $localStorage.userdetails.isAuthenticated == true)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are basically creating a state change interceptor.

The thing is, on every one of your branches in '$stateChangeStart' you have a $state.go . Since this is an interceptor, every time you invoke $state.go , the handler for $stateChangeStart will be invoked, and this is why you get this invocation loop that ends with that error.

You need to write the handler in a way that has at least one branch that does not invoke $state.go

Here is how we implemented it:

```
//The list of states that do not need authentication (like auth)
var authorizedStates = ['auth', 'someOtherAuthorizesState', 'etc'];

// This method reports if a state is one of the authorizes states
var isChildOfAuthorizedStated = function (stateName) {
  var isChild = false;
  authorizedStates.forEach(function (state) {
    if (stateName.indexOf(state) === 0) {
      isChild = true;
    }
  });
  return isChild;
};

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
  // The stateChangeStart handler
  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    // Check if the future state is not an authorized state 
    // and if the user is not authenticated. 
    if (!isChildOfAuthorizedStated(toState.name) && !Auth.isAuthenticated()) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go('auth');
    }
);
```

Comment: It still reports Maximum range exceeded

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a redirection loop.
You need to check whether the new route is already the route where you want to send your client to.

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeStart", function (event, next, current) {
    if (next == 'my-auth-page') {
        // already going to auth page no redirect needed
    } else {
        // not going to auth page, we should redirect now
        $location.path('my-auth-page');
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is going in infinite as you are doing `$state.go` in both cases, You could should not do `$state` redirection user is authorized & second condition is proper which is in else block

```
   if ((!$localStorage.userdetails || !$localStorage.userdetails.isAuthenticated) 
           && toState.name != 'auth') { //<--this condition will stop infinite loop
        //If User not authenticated
        //GO to the Authentication State
        $state.go('auth');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
```

**Update**

Other thing which I wanted to point out about your code is `$stateChangeStart` should be inside a run block(which initialize exactly after config block) so that It would be common for all state & will initialized this condition at the starting of your app

**Code**

```
app.run(function($rootScope){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {

        if ($localStorage.userdetails && $localStorage.userdetails.isAuthenticated == true) {
              if ((!$localStorage.userdetails || !$localStorage.userdetails.isAuthenticated) 
               && toState.name != 'auth') { //<--this condition will stop infinite loop
            //If User not authenticated
            //GO to the Authentication State
            $state.go('auth');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

Also do use service to store `UserDetails` using `$rootScope` in AngulaJs is considered as bad code practice.

Comment: yes i know i did it in hasty to store in rootScope.. Let me Apply your corrections

Comment: @ChanX take you time & let me know..Glad to help you..Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use $state.go("main", {}, {notify:false}); for not notify to "$stateChangeStart"event and not allow the event loop.

```
$state.go("main", {}, {notify:false});
```