# angularjs + ui-router: redirect to login page when user is not logged in on each state change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a simple blog application with angularjs and ui-router and I want to listen for each state change and check if user is logged in. In case he isn't I want to redirect him to the login page.

The scenario is quite simple and I was trying to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212182/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-redirect-to-login-page) with no luck.

This is the relevant code:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true
    });
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('blogs');
});

app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, UserService){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    console.log("state change: from state: " + fromState.name + " to state: " + toState.name);
        let loggedIn = UserService.isLoggedIn();
        if (toState.name !== 'app.login' && !loggedIn){
            event.preventDefault();
            $state.go('app.login');
    });
});
```

Where 'app.login' is defined as the login state and 'blogs' is the url of my main feed that I want the app will go to at startup.

When looking into chrome console, when no user is logged in, i see:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
state change: from state:  to state: app.blogs
state change: from state:  to state: app.login
state change: from state:  to state: app.blogs
state change: from state:  to state: app.login
state change: from state:  to state: app.blogs
state change: from state:  to state: app.login
state change: from state:  to state: app.blogs
state change: from state:  to state: app.login
state change: from state:  to state: app.blogs
state change: from state:  to state: app.login
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:68)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:15753)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:15986)
    at bootstrapApply (angular.js:1658)
    at Object.invoke (angular.js:4473)
    at doBootstrap (angular.js:1656)
    at Object.bootstrap (angular.js:1676)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bootstrap.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7b71f5eb02d2540fe63f:520)
    at fn (bootstrap 7b71f5eb02d2540fe63f:75)
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.5/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:8080/login/login.html".
```

And it appears for several times. Also - the url is jumping between /login and /blogs.

What am I doing wrong?

(Edit: I added some debug to the console.log)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For some reason this code worked:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $state, $location, UserService){
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
        let loggedIn = UserService.isLoggedIn();
        if  (toState.name !== 'app.login' && !loggedIn){
            $location.url('/login');
        }
    });
});
```

I changed the way I'm redirecting to the login page from **$state.go** to 
**$location.url**.

Each time I used the `$state.go` it fired another `$stateChangeStart` event and this was, apparently, wrong.
In this way the `event.preventDefault()` is not necessary.

Comment: you could use  $state.go('app.login',{notify:false});

Answer (score 2):

You could use "**transitionTo**". 
Replace 
`$location.url('/login');`
with
`$state.transitionTo('login');`
ui-router @version v0.2.18