# How to suspend the ui-router state in app.js prior to authenticating a user login

Tags: angularjs

I've recently added a login feature to my AngularJS app.

I have a `modal login`, a login `service`, and its associated login `controller`. The modal works fine and does indeed return the user/password, which I can capture in my `app.js` in the `.then()` section here - `loginService.loginModal().then`. So far, so good.

However, I'm trying to SUSPEND state in my `app.js`. Currently I'm having issues with this, as my application continues to render the main page in the background as soon as my `login modal` appears. This also means that I can't display the proper `userId` on the main page.

I've tried to use `event.preventDefault();`, then `$state.go` once the user is authenticated; however, the prevent is causing an infinite loop in Angular.

```js
(function () {
'use strict';
angular.module('rg', [
'ui.router',
'ui.bootstrap',
'ui.dashboard',
'kendo.directives'       
]).run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'userService', 'loginService', init]);

function init($rootScope, $state, userService, loginService) {
$rootScope.rageSessionVars = {};
$rootScope.$state = $state;

$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {            
    
    var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;

    if (requireLogin && typeof $rootScope.userID == "undefined") {
    
 //event.preventDefault(); // CAUSING AN INFINITE LOOP ERR IN ANGULAR !!!
    // THE APP NEEDS TO BE SUSPENDED HERE UNTIL USER IS AUTHENTICATED !!
      
 loginService.loginModal().then(function (user) {
            
     $rootScope.userID = user.userId;
     initRz();
     return $state.go(toState.name, toParams);
 })                

    }
});        

function initRz() {                           
 userService.initRazor(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
     var response = data.status;
     if (response.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
  userService.openUserSession(razorEnvJson).then(function (data) {
      var sessionID = data.data[0];
      $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID = sessionID;
      $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID = $rootScope.userID;                                
  });
     }
 });             
}
}
})();
```

And here is my routing config. It's note-worthy to say that I ONLY use the 'main' route, as my left nav menu contains a Kendo treeview in place of a standard routing menu:

```js
angular
    .module('rage')
    .config(config);

function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
    $stateProvider
        
        .state('main', {
            url: "/dashboard",
            templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            data: { pageTitle: 'RG', requireLogin: true }            
        })
        .state('login', {
            url: "/login",
            templateUrl: "app/views/login-view.html",
            controller: 'LoginCtrl'
}
```

**** UPDATED $stateChangeStart EVENT CODE ****

I get past the `if (requireLogin` section, but once it hits `$state.go` it throws an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'requireLogin' of undefined`. So, I failed to re-route to the `login` view.

```js
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
    
    var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;

    if (requireLogin && typeof $rootScope.userID == "undefined") {             
 $state.go('login');    // ERROR WHEN ATTEMPTING TO RE-ROUTE !!!
    }
});
```

*** UPDATE, SEPT 18, 2015, USING RESOLVE IN UI-ROUTER ***

Using `resolve:` in `ui-router` worked out for the most part; except I'm still seeing some page-rendering in the background. I was hoping to suspend all view-rendering UNTIL my loginService was resolved.

```js
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboard");
$stateProvider
.state('main', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    templateUrl: "app/views/dashboard.html",
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    data: { pageTitle: 'RAGE', requireLogin: true },
    resolve: {
 authUser: ['$rootScope', 'loginService', 'userService', function ($rootScope, loginService, userService) {
     return loginService.loginModal().then(function (user) {
  $rootScope.userID = user.userId;
  initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService);
        return user;
     })
 }]
    }
})
.state('login', {
    url: "/login",
    templateUrl: "app/views/login-view.html",
    controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})
}
function initSession(user, $rootScope, loginService, userService) {

    userService.getInitParams().then(function (envJson) {
        $rootScope.rageSessionVars = razorEnvJson;
        userService.initRz(envJson).then(function (data) {
            var response = data.status;
            if (response.match(/SUCCESS/g)) {
                userService.openUserSession(envJson).then(function (data) {
                    var sessionID = data.data[0];
                    $rootScope.rageSessionVars.sessionID = sessionID;
                    $rootScope.rageSessionVars.userID = $rootScope.userID; // *** HOW TO SUSPEND ALL CODE UNTIL userID IS ASSIGNED ??? ***
                    console.log("sessionID = " + sessionID);

                    $rootScope.rageSessionVars.currDashboardName = "Default";
                });
            }
        });
```

I'd like to know if I'm missing something in my logic. Perhaps there's a `Promise` that I need to implement in the routing somewhere.

Your advice is appreciated.

regards,

Bob

Comment: define a separate  service, contoller+state. If user is not logged-in in '$stateChangeStart' event, than do $state.go to that state. move modal code to that controller.

Comment: I don't fully understand. I already have a separate `loginService`, then in the `.then()` section I do a `$state.go(toState.name, toParams)`. And by the way, I've updated my post to show the routing config.

Comment: --create a new state (may be login), its control should have your modal code (loginService.loginModal()....)
-- Inside $stateChangeStart event, if(loginFails){$state.go(new_state_with_login_modal)}else {do_nothing}

Comment: Okay, I think I'm following now. I can still keep the `$stateChangeStart` event inside my app.js, but if login fails then I can `$state.go` to the login route. And subsequently, inside my new `login` route I can reroute to my `main` route when user is authenticated ?

Comment: event.defaultPrevented = true;  this should also work

Comment: I'm failing on `$state.go('login')`. Please see my original post where I've added some code at the end of my post. See `*** UPDATED $stateChangeStart EVENT CODE `

Comment: before `$state.go('login')` add  `event.defaultPrevented = true; `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use ui-routers resolve. You don't need any $stateChangeStart and it will "hang" until the promise is resolved

Comment: I was looking into `resolve` yesterday in fact, but unclear how to implement. And even using the event.preventDefault() is causing it to hand.

Comment: Using `resolve:` in `ui-router` worked out for the most part; however I had to post another question for details on how to implement the loginService.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the `$stateChangeStart` event, use `$locationChangeStart`. `event.preventDefault()` should work

Comment: preventDefault() just hangs in Angular with Infinite Loop error. Apparently it hangs until the login promise is resolved. There's another poster with the same scenario from last year, and yet he uses the same preventDefault(). Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27212182/angularjs-ui-router-how-to-redirect-to-login-page