# $stateChangeStart event continuing after state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm attempting to send the user to a specific 'closed' UI State in Angular using the following:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  // check the destination is active
  if(toState.data.isClosed) { // note that the 'closed' state has isClosed set to false
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('closed');
  }
  $rootScope.data = toState.data;  // getting executed twice after our state transition to 'closed'
  $log.debug(toState);
});
```

The issue I'm having is that `$rootScope.data = toState.data` is getting called twice AFTER we've transitioned to the 'closed' state.

On the first time `$startChangeStart` executes when navigating to our 'order' state with `data.isClosed = true` set in the router, the state is changed to 'closed' and the code in question doesn't get executed.

As we are changing states to 'closed' now, `$startChangeStart` gets triggered again, and the code in question executes for the first time with toState being our 'closed' state.

Strangely, the code is then subsequently executed, starting after the if() logic with toState being the original state of 'order'... meaning that when everything is loaded up, the $rootScope.data variable contains the data from 'order' rather than 'closed'. Adding a few breakpoints and the debugging code above confirms.

Any explanations?

**Update**

Due to the execution pattern with the state transition to the 'closed' state, I've added a return to ensure that the continued execution after the `$state.go()` call is terminated. Revised code:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
  // check the destination is active
  if(toState.data.isClosed) { // note that the 'closed' state has isClosed set to false
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('closed');
    return;
  }
  $rootScope.data = toState.data;  // getting executed twice after our state transition to 'closed'
  $log.debug(toState);
});
```

This is now working as expected, but I'm not sure it's 'correct'.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a PLNKR? It doesn't seem to be happening here: http://plnkr.co/edit/30IohTOqPHbOcGluMzaX?

Comment: Your plnkr doesn't seem to actually transition the state - the post and exit alert get fired immediately after the $state.transitionTo() and still contain the state2 data - http://plnkr.co/edit/loDq6xNmONBDRCTlQe8H

Comment: It seems a bit strange to do that in state change handler. Maybe you could do it using a redirect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with return statement is simple correct. I created [this playground](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpGc9NRWq1mHLx3zWCpY?p=preview), where you can test that.

Let's have these states. Firstly some state with isClosed false - which should not be managed by our event listener

```
  .state('state1', {
    url: "/state1",
    template: "<div>this is a state1</div>",
    data: { isClosed : false },
  })
  .state('state2', {
    url: "/state2",
    template: "<div>this is a state2</div>",
    data: { isClosed : false },
  })
```

and these will be caught and redirected

```
  .state('stateClosed1', {
    url: "/stateClosed1",
    template: "<div>this is a stateClosed1</div>",
    data: { isClosed : true },
  })
  .state('stateClosed2', {
    url: "/stateClosed2",
    template: "<div>this is a stateClosed2</div>",
    data: { isClosed : true },
  })
  // even this would be handy
  .state('closed', {
    url: "/closed",
    template: "<div>this is a closed</div>",
    data: { isClosed : false },
  })
```

Now, whenever we go to any state, the event **`$stateChangeStart`** is fired. So if we go to "not handled" states *(state1, state2)* - the event will be triggered once.

If we go to handled states *(stateClosed1, stateClosed2)*, event is fired always twice:

- go to stateClosed1
- go to closed

Just to be sure: **the event is really fired twice**. And that's why we should write these listeners rather like this *(get out ASAP)*:

```
  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState, toParams
                                                    , fromState, fromParams) {

    // get out if we already go to state, which is about to be handled below
    if(toState.name === "closed") {
      return;
    }

    // check the destination is active
    if (toState.data.isClosed) { // note that the 'closed' 
      event.preventDefault();    // state has isClosed set to false 
      $state.go('closed');
      return; 
    }
    $rootScope.data = toState.data; // getting executed 'closed'
                                    // twice after our state transition to 
                                    // only if above if does not contain return
    console.debug(toState);
  });
```

In fact, this solution (getting out as soon as possible), was issue in these Q & A:

- [Angular ui router - Redirection doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26135382/1679310)
- [How can I fix 'Maximum call stack size exceeded' AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25028597/1679310)