# UI-Router state changes but URL and template don't

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm doing some onStateChange authorization like this:

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .run(['$rootScope', '$state', 'Auth', function ($rootScope, $state, Auth) {

        $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

            console.log(toState);

            if (!Auth.authorize(toState.data.allow)) {

                console.log("Not authorized");
                $state.go('app.auth.login', { redirect: toState.name });
            }

            console.log('Authorized');
        });

    }]);
```

Now, when I go to an unauthorized route, it acts as it should, up to a point. The authorization fails and it tries to redirect to `app.auth.login`. This is shown in the `console.log`s:

```
Object {url: "/", templateUrl: "modules/live/index.html", name: "app.live.index", data: Object}
app.routes.js:225 Not authorized
app.routes.js:222 Object {url: "/auth/login?redirect", templateUrl: "modules/auth/login.html", controller: "LoginController", name: "app.auth.login", data: Object}controller: "LoginController"data: Objectname: "app.auth.login"templateUrl: "modules/auth/login.html"url: "/auth/login?redirect"__proto__: Object
app.routes.js:229 Authorized
app.routes.js:229 Authorized
```

But the URL stays at the original state (the first attempted state), and I don't see the login screen. The `LoginController` never gets called (there's a console.log at the start that doesn't show.

If I visit `/auth/login` I see the login screen as intended.

Here's my `app.routes.js`:

```
/*****
* Auth
******/
.state('app.auth', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>',
    data: {
        allow: access.everyone
    }
})

.state('app.auth.login', {
    url: '/auth/login?redirect',
    templateUrl: 'modules/auth/login.html',
    controller: 'LoginController'
})

.state('app.auth.logout', {
    url: '/auth/logout',
    controller: 'LogoutController'
})

/*****
* Live
******/
.state('app.live', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/live',
    data: {
        allow: access.live
    }
})

.state('app.live.index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'modules/live/index.html'
});
```

What can be causing this odd behaviour?

Comment: I think you should use resolve(promises) instead of "stateChangeStart". Because stateChangeStart also creates problem when you refresh page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens in this cases, that we do forget to solve situation:

- user is already *(previously)* redirected === user is going to `$state.go('app.auth.login')` ... no need to redirect

And we should not redirect in such case:

```
$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", 
  function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

   if (toState.name === 'app.auth.login')
   {
     // get out of here, we are already redirected
     return;
   }
```

And once we do decide to redirect, we should stop current navigation with **`event.perventDefault();`**

```
    if (!Auth.authorize(toState.data.allow)) {
        // here
        event.perventDefault();
        $state.go('app.auth.login', { redirect: toState.name });
    }
    ...
```

See more for example in this [$stateChangeStart event continuing after state change](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27532388/1679310) or that  [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310) with a working plunker

Comment: That does get rid of the second "Authorized", but I still stay on the same *unauthorized* page.

Comment: I updated my answer, also, please check this for detailed example and working plunker http://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310