# Change page with $state.go()

Tags: angularjs, routes, authorization, angular-ui-router, state

it's probably a rookie mistake but I am having trouble changing my page using:

`$state.go('login');`

My routing looks as following:

```
$stateProvider
   .state('login', {
       url: "/login",
       templateUrl: "./auth/login.html",
       controller: 'loginCtrl'
   })
```

I also added a

`$rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, next) {...}`

just to check if it gets there after I use **$state.go()** and yes; it gets there but it does not change my page or URL at all. Changing the page works fine with `ui-sref="login"` inside a view.html.

Other syntaxes I tried:

```
$state.go('login', null, {options: { location : true }  } );
$state.go('login', {}, {location : true});
```

Btw, what I am trying to accomplish is redirecting to a login-page when the user is not authorized inside the **$stageChangeStart-event**.

Any ideas?

Comment: `$stateChangeStart` gets fired at the **start** of the statechange and doesn't necessarily mean it succeeds. `$stateChangeSuccess` is a better test. Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: There are no errors in the console. As soon as $state.go('login') is fired it immediately gets inside the **$stateChangeStart**. When it's done I get inside **stateChangeSuccess**. Do I need **event.preventDefault()** in order to change page/url?

Comment: No, `event.preventDefault()` would stop the state from changing. I am not sure what the problem is if there are no errors and it's working with `ui-sref`... very confusing. The only thing that is new to me in your code is using `./auth/login.html` rather than just `auth/login.html` that I would use, but I doubt that will make any difference.

Comment: One thing you should check - put a `console.log` statement in `loginCtrl` and see if it's being run? If it is, check the network tab of your dev tools and ensure the `GET` request for `login.html` is succeeding...

Answer (score 0):

Visit [Angular ui router - Redirection doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26135382/angular-ui-router-redirection-doesnt-work-at-all) . It gave me a more clear idea of what I was doing wrong.

The actual solution for me was found at the following page answered by **frankwallis**:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/600

I replaced my default `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/yourpage');` with

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise( function($injector, $location) {
     var $state = $injector.get("$state");
     $state.go("app.home");
});
```

Too bad I don't really understand the solution but atleast it works now!