# Angular ui-router: warn user when leaving a specific page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

In my angular app, I need to warn the user before he **leaves** a **specific** page, not every page.

If I use a `$locationChangeStart` within the controller of the page    where I want to warn the user, it will trigger even when coming to    the page, which is not desired.

If I use it on the parent controller, it will trigger everywhere and    I have to add a complex if/else or switch structure to basically tell    it to never trigger unless a user is abandoning that specific state.

How do I detect that a user is actually *leaving* (and only leaving) a specific `state` using UI-Router?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use an event (and hook on your own listener)

#### [$stateChangeStart](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#events_$statechangestart)

> Fired when the state transition begins. You can use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the transition from happening and then the transition promise will be rejected with a 'transition prevented' value.
>
> ...
>
> **Example:**

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){
    event.preventDefault();
    // transitionTo() promise will be rejected with
    // a 'transition prevented' error
})
```

There is a detailed explanation and working plunker in this Q & A:

- [Confusing $locationChangeSuccess and $stateChangeStart](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25872219/1679310)
- [Angularjs ui-router. How to redirect to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27212182/1679310)
- [Angular ui router - Redirection doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26135382/1679310)

Comment: Might need to add a: event.returnValue = 'something'; below event.preventDefault(); for the alert to show.

Comment: Is this still viable? According to ui-router docs: "State change events are deprecated, DISABLED and replaced by Transition Hooks as of version 1.0."