# Issues on angular ui-router when Auth

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I put notify to true, does not render the login.html, is a blank page. If I put as false, but returns renders me several errors in the console:

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at $.resolve (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at b (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at Object.x.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at Object.x.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at app.js:317
    at p.$broadcast (angular.min.js:3)
    at Object.x.transitionTo (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at Object.x.go (angular-ui-router.min.js:1)
    at app.js:317
    at p.$broadcast (angular.min.js:3)
```

My code router:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
   function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

        var shouldLogin = !$window.sessionStorage.token && !AuthenticationService.isLogged;

        $rootScope.Authenticated = shouldLogin;

        //redirect only if both isAuthenticated is false and no token is set
        // if (!AuthenticationService.isLogged && !$window.sessionStorage.token) {
        //     $state.go('login');
        // }

        //console.log($rootScope.Authenticated);

        if(shouldLogin) {
            $state.go('login', {}, {notify: false, location: false});
            event.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

    });
```

Comment: The Maximum call stack usually occurs when you have and infinite callback. Try to debug your code thinking about this aspect.

Comment: don't use `$state.go` here.  that causes another `$stateChangeStart`, which causes this function to be evaluated again, which causes another `$state.go`, etc.

Comment: I resolved using $location.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, that you can go your way, just ... add a line to NOT redirect, when already going to login:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
  function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    var alreadyGoingToLogin = toState.name === "login";
    if(alreadyGoingToLogin) {
      return
    }
    ...
```

Check these with working examples:

- [Angular ui router - Redirection doesn't work at all](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26135382/1679310)
- [Angularjs ui-router. How to redirect to login page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27212182/1679310)